# Cancel Windows Explorer folder search after pressing 'up' arrow

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, search

In Windows Explorer (Windows 10), I can type into the search box at the top right to filter the files that are shown.
Normally I can clear a search by pressing the little 'x' at the right of the search box, or by deleting the text in the search box.

Supposing that I press the 'up' arrow to navigate to the folder above (while a search is active), then I can't find a way to then cancel the search, aside from completely re-typing the folder path into the address bar.

The 'Close Search' ribbon button doesn't seem to cancel the search nor return me to the unfiltered folder view that I'm after.

Is there a way to cancel the search in Windows Explorer having already clicked the 'up' arrow to navigate to the folder above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `x` is transferred from the Search box to the right side
of the title of
`> Search Results in ...`.

Clicking that `x` will stop the search.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @harrymc - sadly, I don't even see that 'x'.
It could be that they've messed it up in recent builds of Windows 10 perhaps.

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks again @harrymc.  What I find is that as soon as the green bar has gone all the way across to the right of the address-bar, then the 'x' is replaced with a 'refresh' symbol.  Clicking it probably does cancel the search, but doesn't sort out the address-bar, which still displays "Search Results..."
I think that this might just be a Windows bug - the behaviour makes no logical sense (to me at least).

Comment: Once the green bar has gone all the way, then the search is supposed to be finished. Refresh will redo the search.

Comment: Thank you, but I think we're thinking different things as regards the search being cancelled.  Let's say that I'm in folder d:\temp.  I search for say "test", then I press the 'up' button, intending to navigate up to 'd:\'.  Instead, my address bar shows "Search results in....".  Now I try to cancel the search such that my address-bar shows either "d:\" or "d:\temp" again.  I cannot find a way to do this.  Obviously it's not an issue if 'd:\' was where I want to be (as I can quickly retype it), but in a more deeply nested folder it can be rather more painful.

Comment: After stopping the search, you may return to the previous screen by clicking on the left-arrow at the left, or by typing Alt+left-arrow.

Comment: Oh, fancy that - you're right - 2 clicks of the left arrow get me back to where I was before.  That's not quite the answer I was expecting, but at least I can use it to get back to where I was.  Thanks for your help @harrymc